# Passing NSString from a ViewController to a NSObject

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller, nsstring, nsobject

Hi Im trying to pass a NSString thats in a ViewController over to a NSString in an NSObject.
Here is the code that I am using in my NSObject to call the string and pass it to my new string.

```
    RegisterDeviceViewController *S = [[RegisterDeviceViewController alloc] init];
tempRegCode = S.checkString;
NSLog(@"tempRegCode=%@",tempRegCode);
```

the problem being once the button it pressed on the view that starts the method in my NSObject it works sweet however nothing gets passed to tempRegCode.. here is my Log.

> [Session started at 2011-05-03 09:27:35 +1200.]
>   2011-05-03 09:27:36.264 instaCode1.3[1456:207] yum yum feed me more cookie!! func=ERROR
>   Code=1
>   Text=Please Register Device
>   2011-05-03 09:27:36.266 instaCode1.3[1456:207] cookieCode = code1
>   2011-05-03 09:27:37.983 instaCode1.3[1456:207] alerts.m OK button pressed
>   2011-05-03 09:27:49.539 instaCode1.3[1456:207] Users Registration is '22222-22222-22222-22222'
>   2011-05-03 09:27:49.540 instaCode1.3[1456:207] tempRegCode=(null)

As you can see at the end there 'tempRegCode=(null)??

EDIT::
This is how I passed the variable to checkString

```
- (IBAction)submitRegistration:(id)sender{
//NSLog(@"submit Registration button has been pressed");

//add text format here
checkString = regTextField.text;
NSLog(@"Users Registration is '%@'",checkString);

regConnection *Reg= [[regConnection alloc] init];
[Reg startRegConnect];
```

}

Comment: Perhaps you can show an example of the attempt you made to pass the value ? passing it as a method parameter or setting a Property or variable ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you set the property `checkString` to anything in the `-init` method of your view controller? If you don't, it will default to NULL.

Something like this (in your RegisterDeviceViewController.m file):

```
- (id)init {
    self.tempRegCode = @"My String";
}
```

If you are trying to get a string that is in an already-instanciated copy of RegisterDeviceViewController, you need a reference to that copy, not to a newly allocated one. For example, if you have an instance of RegisterDeviceViewController in your XIB file, use an IBOutlet to this instance in your NSObject subclass then call `-tempRegCode` on that instance.

Comment: yea I'm setting it off a UITexField like this

checkString = regTextField.text;

Comment: Why does the view controller have any text within regTextField upon init?

Comment: thats not my code adam, that was a suggestion from Kyle, My code is above.. sorry I didn't show how I was passing the text from the textfield over to the NSString because I had tested it and it was showing the code that was passed to it.. Thus I thought the error was over in the NSObject... but I have updated my post and added all the code involved with the weird problem.